# Character encoding issues when upgrading EE 1.7.3 to EE 2.5.5

Tags: ee2, ee1, update, character-encoding

I have an EE 1.7.3 with charset iso-8859-1. If i do the update all the umlauts in the browser show up as ?.

So I converted the data from the database (the whole database) 1.7.3 before the update to utf8. Now EE 2.5.5 cuts every string after an umlaut after the update.

I find no way to change the contents of 1.7.3 showing up correctly without typing all the content new.

Anybody had this problem before?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a visual example of pre and post? Also when you converted database to UTF8 did everything display properly in EE 1.7.3 before upgrade? Then lastly, are there differences between the front end display versus the control panel display of entries?

Comment: I haven't had this specific issue, but you might be able to simply edit the EE upgrade scripts and remove the bits which convert tables to UTF8.

Comment: If found out that EE 1.7.3 IS Latin and not utf-8. So if I have iso-8859-1 choosen in the CP the content in the browser looks fine. When i change to uft-8 the umlautes are black signs with a question mark in it.
The database seems to be utf-8 because the collation is latin1_swedish_ci and in the tables I can see the umlauts correct (ä, ö, ü).

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an exact answer, but I had a problem similar to this. I was using Navicat and MAMP and I had character set issues in my local set up. I wrote [a blog post](https://supergeekery.com/geekblog/comments/mamp-and-navicat-and-character-set-hell) about it for my own reference because it tripped me up several times. Not sure if this helps your issue though.